# How can I connect back to the firebase realtime database after running Google Cloud Functions Emulator

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have deployed a **google cloud function** for my flutter app to send push notifications to a given user when a new node is inserted in firebase realtime database but it's not working, so **I decided to debug functions with VS Code**, which I'm using on a Windows machine to develop the flutter app.

Hence, I followed a series of steps, following a tutorial, all of them in terminal, and **I got connected to a local version of the database** - I was told the debugger to be **listening on port 9229**. So I couldn't see the real database data, that appeared empty. After testing without finding a solution, I wanted to work with real data again, so I tried to stop functions and uninstall google cloud functions emulator, but **I still cannot see any database data**.

**So the question is: How can I get to connect to the realtime database on the server again?**

In case it helps to diagnose the problem, the steps I followed were these:

-In the project folder:

```
npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
```

-Then in the functions folder:

```
firebase setup:web
```

node

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({
  "databaseURL": "https://YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.appspot.com",
  "projectId": "YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT"
}))) //using my own data

functions start

set FIREBASE_CONFIG="{\"databaseURL\":\"https://YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.firebaseio.com\",\"storageBucket\":\"YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.appspot.com\",\"projectId\":\"YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT\"}" //using my own data here too

functions deploy --trigger-http --timeout 600s YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME //using my function name

functions debug myFunction
```

Then I got:

```
Debugger for myFunction listening on port 9229.
```

And then in .vscode\launch.json I added:

```
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach Firebase",
        "port": 9229,
        "preLaunchTask": "Google Cloud Emulator"
    }
```

...

Then I tried to exit, so I entered:

-In the functions folder:

```
functions stop
```

-In the project folder:

```
npm uninstall -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
```

...

I don't see the firebase realtime database data yet.

Answer (score 0):

I already have found the reason why I didn't receive data from the firebase database, and it was not related to the port the debugger was listening. It was a change in the database content, that had nothing to do with this process, what caused the app not to show any data from the realtime database. Anyway I deployed firebase again just in case using simply

```
firebase deploy
```